# Any provision to push message between "Queues" by change the Queue name dynamically in stream @Input("suffix"+"QueueA")and@Input("suffix"+"QueueA")

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

Is there any provision to push message between two "Queues"  by change the Queue name dynamically in cloud.stream `@Input("suffix"+"SampleQueueA")` and `@Input("suffix"+"SampleQueueB")`

This use case with Sprig cloud stream using messaging server RabbitMQ.
I tried pushing messages into two different  Queues by dynamically changing the Queue name.

```java
# Input bindings used for testing
spring:
rabbitmq:
host: 127.0.0.1
virtual-host: /defaultVH
username: guest
password: guest


cloud:
stream:
bindings: 
ClientSampleQueueA:
binder: rabbit-A
contentType: application/x-java-object
group: groupA
destination: ClientSampleQueueA

VendorSampleQueueA:
binder: rabbit-A
contentType: application/x-java-object
group: groupA
destination: VendorSampleQueueA

# cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination: customerId-1
# spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.destination: customerId-2


binders:
rabbit-A:
defaultCandidate: false
inheritEnvironment: false
type: rabbit
environment:
spring:
rabbitmq:
host: 127.0.0.1
virtualHost: /vhA
username: guest
password: guest
port: 5672
connection-timeout: 10000
```

```
interface Sink {

String INPUT1 = "ClientSampleQueueA";
String INPUT2 = "VendorSampleQueueA";


@Input(INPUT1)
SubscribableChannel input1();


@Input(INPUT2)
SubscribableChannel input2();

}
```

```
@Bean(name = "sourceChannel")
public MessageChannel localChannel() {
return new DirectChannel();
}
```

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sourceChannel")
private MessageChannel localChannel;
```

Want to resolve the Queue dynamically by Object parameter.

```java
private void sendMessage(Object body, Object contentType) {
        localChannel.send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(body,
                new MessageHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType))));
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean or what localChannel is. However see routingKeyExpression rabbitmq producer property. However, the destinations must be the same so that the queues are bound to the same exchange. The consumer groups must be different.

Comment: Thanks Gary for quick reply, I have added the reference of localChannel.

Comment: Thanks Gary for quick reply, I have added the reference of localChannel. I want to switch between Queue's based on Queue name in runtime, configured only in configuration file no where else in classes.

Answer (score 0):

But what is subscribed to `localChannel`.

As I said in my comment:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.ClientSampleQueueA.destination=commonDest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.ClientSampleQueueA.group=ClientSampleQueueA
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.ClientSampleQueueA.bindingRoutingKey=ClientSampleQueueA
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.VendorSampleQueueA.destination=commonDest
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.VendorSampleQueueA.bindingRoutingKey=VendorSampleQueueA
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.VendorSampleQueueA.group=ClientSampleQueueA
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sourceChannel.destination=commonDest
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.sourceChannel.routingKeyExpression=headers.routeTo
```

and then

```
private void sendMessage(Object body, Object contentType) {
    localChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(body)
          .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType)
          .setHeader("routeTo", "VendorSampleQueueA")
          .build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you  Gary , I will give shot with this.